# overloaded ‘QString(int)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, qt4.7

The following code fragment gives the compilation error
`call of overloaded ‘QString(int)’ is ambiguous` with qt 4.7.3
(system is linux 64bit, debian unstable)

```
struct QSAConnection
{
  QSAConnection() : sender(0), signal(0), function_ref() { }
  QSAConnection(QObject *send, const char *sig, QSObject ref)
    : sender(send), signal(QLatin1String(sig)), function_ref(ref) { }
  QObject *sender;
  QString signal;
  QSObject function_ref;
};
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

The relevant bit is this line:

```
QSAConnection() : sender(0), signal(0), function_ref() { }
```

Since `signal` is a `QString`, the `signal(0)` bit is trying to call a constructor on the `QString` class that takes an integer as its only parameter. `QString` has no such constructor according to the Qt documentation. It does however have a constructor taking a `char`, and a `QChar` which has an implicit conversion from `int`. I expect it's ambiguous between those two.

Did you mean this instead?

```
QSAConnection() : sender(0), signal(), function_ref() { }
```

Which will default initialize `signal`. Note that technically it's not necessary to include it in the initializer list at all in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good thing. If it was not ambiguous, you might hit a null-pointer exception on `QString::QString(char const* src)`. This is a common mistake with `std::string`.